# PowerShellのモジュールをPowerShell Galleryに登録したいのですがなぜかできません。どうしたら登録できるのでしょうか

Tags: powershell

下記にPowerShellのモジュールを作成しました。
https://github.com/or1ko/japanese-string-utils-ps

このモジュールをPowerShell Galleryに登録しようとPublish-Moduleを実行したのですが、
下記のようなエラーが出力され登録できません。どうしたら登録できるのでしょうか。

※ NuGetApiKeyの値は実際の値から変更しています。

```
japanese-string-utils-ps> Publish-Module -Path .\JapaneseStringUtils\ -NuGetApiKey "5aa41459-e653-4683-1b16-29da8244afac"
Publish-PSArtifactUtility : モジュール 'JapaneseStringUtils': '接続が切断されました: 送信時に、予期しないエラーが発生し
ました。。
' を発行できませんでした。
発生場所 C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1227 文字:17
+                 Publish-PSArtifactUtility -PSModuleInfo $moduleInfo `
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error]、WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToPublishTheModule,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
```

PowerShellのバージョンは下記になります。

```
> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.906
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.906
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

-Verboseを付与して実行した結果は下記になります。

```
Publish-Module -Path .\JapaneseStringUtils\ -NuGetApiKey "5aa41459-e653-4683-1b16-29da8244afac"  -Verbose
詳細: リポジトリの詳細、Name = 'PSGallery'、Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'、IsTrusted =          'False'、IsRegistered = 'True'。
詳細: リポジトリの詳細、Name = 'PSGallery'、Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'、IsTrusted =
'False'、IsRegistered = 'True'。
詳細: 発行先:'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/'。
詳細: パス 'C:\Users\or1ko\Desktop\japanese-string-utils-ps\JapaneseStringUtils\JapaneseStringUtils.psm1'
からモジュールを読み込んでいます。
詳細: モジュール 'JapaneseStringUtils' が 'C:\Users\or1ko\Desktop\japanese-string-utils-ps\JapaneseStringUtils'
で見つかりました。
詳細: パス 'C:\Users\or1ko\AppData\Local\Temp\656910045\JapaneseStringUtils\JapaneseStringUtils.psm1'
からモジュールを読み込んでいます。
詳細: リポジトリの詳細、Name = 'PSGallery'、Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'、IsTrusted =
'False'、IsRegistered = 'True'。
詳細: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
詳細: 指定されたリソース名を使用しています: 'PSGallery'。
詳細: PackageManagement プロバイダー 'NuGet' のプロバイダー オブジェクトを取得しています。
詳細: 指定された Location は 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/items/psscript'、PackageManagementProvider は
'NuGet' です。
詳細: Searching repository
'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/items/psscript/FindPackagesById()?id='JapaneseStringUtils'' for ''.
詳細: Total package yield:'0' for the specified package 'JapaneseStringUtils'.
詳細: リポジトリの詳細、Name = 'PSGallery'、Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'、IsTrusted =
'False'、IsRegistered = 'True'。
詳細: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
詳細: 指定されたリソース名を使用しています: 'PSGallery'。
詳細: PackageManagement プロバイダー 'NuGet' のプロバイダー オブジェクトを取得しています。
詳細: 指定された Location は 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'、PackageManagementProvider は 'NuGet' です。
詳細: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='JapaneseStringUtils'' for
''.
詳細: Total package yield:'0' for the specified package 'JapaneseStringUtils'.
詳細: 対象 "モジュール 'JapaneseStringUtils' のバージョン '1.0.0'" に対して操作 "Publish-Module" を実行しています。
Publish-PSArtifactUtility : モジュール 'JapaneseStringUtils': '接続が切断されました: 送信時に、予期しないエラーが発生し
ました。。
' を発行できませんでした。
発生場所 C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1227 文字:17
+                 Publish-PSArtifactUtility -PSModuleInfo $moduleInfo `
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error]、WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToPublishTheModule,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
```

Comment: `> C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm` 参考になるかどうかわかりませんが、PowerShellGet 1.1.1.0に上げたら解決した方がいるみたいですね。https://forums.inedo.com/topic/1382/authentication-and-publish-powershell-modules-to-powershell-feed/4

Comment: 質問の回答は自分でも書けますので、解決した内容を回答として投稿してください。48時間後(?)に自身が書いた回答を承認することができると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShellGetのバージョンを2.2.5に変更したところ、apiキーが誤っているというエラーに変わりました。
apiキーの見直したところ、誤った値を指定してたことがわかり、正しいものを使ったところ登録することがでいました。
APIキーの名前を指定してました。「Copy」ボタンでコピーした値が正しかったです。
1.1.1.0に上げただけでは解決できなかったですが、最新のPowerShellGetを使ってないことに気づけたので、解決できました。

コメントおよび質問のcloseの仕方を教えていただいてありがとうございます。